# Finding dots on a vector

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

Is there efficient way to find a dot on a vector in unity (using c# script)? I have two coordinates and I want to make a list of all the dots on this vector with a specific distance from each other, lets say its the constant 1. Every way I can think of requires some equations with some unknowns. How can I calcilate it then?

Comment: Post some of your equations with unknowns to show prior effort, and help explain the problem because it's not clear to me what "dots" are. Dot products? Points in space with some specific property? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean two points -(x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,x3), and I want a list of all the points between them(on a stright line) with distance of 1.

Comment: Make an image. The question is still unclear, with a distance of 1 from what? Either edge? Then there are 2 points at most. Or do you mean a dotted line from start to finish? If I check again and this problem is still not explained coherently, I give up.